# Suppose an isolated north pole exists. Then would it surely move along magnetic field line of a bar magnet as written in my book?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, magnetic-fields, kinematics, magnetic-monopoles

My book says that magnetic field lines due to a bar magnet are the path along which a unit north pole would move (if it existed). Will it surely move along the field line?
I mean the two poles of magnet will exert forces whose resultant will always be tangential to field line then which force will act as centripetal force?

Comment: TLDR: The core of Michael Seifert's answer is that the field lines show you the direction of the force that the particle would feel at any given location within the field, but the direction in which a massive particle _moves_ at any given instant in time depends on more than just the force that is applied to it.

Answer (score 0):

A hypothetical isolated magnetic pole (often called a *magnetic monopole*) would feel a force in the direction of the magnetic field lines, and so its acceleration vector would be tangent to a field line at all times.  However, the trajectory traced out by such a monopole does not necessarily follow a field line.  If it did follow a field line, then its *velocity* (rather than its acceleration) would be tangent to a field line at all times.

Note that the above statements apply equally as well to electric charges and their paths relative to electric field lines.  For example, a "light" negative charge such as an electron can orbit a "heavy" positive charge such as a proton in a circular orbit;  in this instance, the trajectory does not follow the field lines.  Similarly, a
"light" north pole could orbit a "heavy" south pole in a circular orbit that does not follow a magnetic field line.